# background color doesnt works properly on react using tailwindCss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, background-color

div has a background color set to black but child components like "locations" and "contact" are without a background color.

my result looks like this:

[image]

I want a black background to be like:

[image]

here is my code written in tailwindcss and react:

```
<div
  id="menu-elements"
  className="flex md:hidden gap-[32px]  flex-col bg-black text-red-500 my-12 mx-6 h-[14px]      tracking-[2px] text-sm leading-[14px] uppercase">
        <Link to="/ourCompany">Our Company</Link>
        <Link to="/locations">Locations</Link>
        <Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
<div
        id="menu-elements"
        className="flex md:hidden gap-[32px]  flex-col bg-black text-red-500 my-12 mx-6 h-[14px] tracking-[2px] text-sm leading-[14px] uppercase"
      >
        <div className="bg-black">
          <Link to="/ourCompany">Our Company</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-black">
          <Link to="/locations">Locations</Link>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-black">
          <Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider removing the `h-[14px]` class from the `<div>` wrapper. This applies `height: 14px` and thus the black background color would only be `14px` high – the height of the `<div>`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="menu-elements" class="flex gap-[32px] flex-col bg-black text-red-500 my-12 mx-6 tracking-[2px] text-sm leading-[14px] uppercase">
  <a href="/ourCompany">Our Company</a>
  <a href="/locations">Locations</a>
  <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```